# Interpreting the Pearson Chi-Square test of a constant Poisson event rate over independent counting experiments

Tags: chi-squared-test, poisson-distribution, p-value

### The Experiment

Consider a set of $N$ independent time segments.

1. Measure the amount of time in given segment: $t_i$
2. Count the number of events that occur in a given segment: $m_i$

An estimate of the overall trigger rate is $R=M/T$ where $T$ and $M$ are the total time and total number of events in this analysis respectively.

The estimated number of events that will in the $i^{th}$ segment, given computed rate above, is $e_i=t_iR$. One can then use Pearson $\chi^2$ test 
$$
X^2 = \sum_{i=1}^N \frac{(m_i-e_i)^2}{e_i}
$$
to compute a test statistic for the data and from that calculate a p-value for $\chi^2 \geq X^2$ given $N-1$ degrees of freedom.

---

### A subset of the data

```
t = numpy.array([  41964.,   65105.,   16178.,   16018.,   27868.,    3293.,
      7153.,   10808.,    7228.,   37028.,   83448.,   86558.,
     25638.,   15268.,   14753.,   25773.,   69998.,    2298.,
      1858.,   28058.,    3788.,   20653.,    5483.,   22238.,
      2933.,    4168.,   31823.,    6358.,   26908.,    7388.,
      4558.,    8068.,   32718.,   34648.,   13588.,   22298.,
     12588.,    2588.,   19972.,    7826.,   26798.,    6998.,
     39253.,   62278.,   71018.,   51338.,   17838.,  106228.,
     19228.,   50038.])
m = numpy.array([ 185.,  322.,   86.,   82.,  132.,   16.,   34.,   66.,   44.,
    176.,  387.,  439.,  138.,   73.,   62.,  115.,  331.,    9.,
      9.,  146.,   16.,  101.,   25.,  111.,   14.,   21.,  160.,
     29.,  111.,   39.,   21.,   34.,  148.,  168.,   64.,  107.,
     58.,   19.,  100.,   29.,  124.,   30.,  173.,  298.,  328.,
    233.,   84.,  493.,   95.,  229.])
```

---

### Code & the results

```py
import numpy
from scipy import stats
R = numpy.sum(m)/numpy.sum(t)
e = t*R
X2, p_rs = stats.chisquare(m,e)
```

- $R = 0.004755$
- $X^2 = 30.71$
- $p_{rs} = 0.9811$

It is unclear to me how to interpret the right-sided (one tail) p-value being so large. If I include all 115 segments in the calculation rather than just the first 50,

- $R = 0.004757$
- $X^2 = 66.59$
- $p_{rs} = 0.9999$

which only worsens my confusion. I cannot see how it is possible that I have such good agreement between the estimated number of events and the measured values. What simple (or not so simple) idea am I missing that makes sense of this?